# The optimal time to start decelerating a craft landing directly on a planet

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, rocket-science

I was playing around with Kerbal Space program and I came across this issue that I hope somebody could help me with.

Suppose there is a craft accelerating radially toward a planet due to gravity, with its thrusters facing towards the surface. The thrusters provide a fixed impulse. Assuming there is no air resistance and the change in weight of the fuel is negligible, when is the optimal time or radius to start decelerating so velocity is zero when the craft reaches the surface?

I assumed the way to solve this was to find functions for velocity and time to the surface given radius. Velocity was easy to derive from kinetic energy in this case, but I could not find a way to relate time and radius (and was told previously there is no way to express it in a $r(t)=f(t)$ way), so that line of thinking seemed to be a dead end to me.
I feel like there must be a way to solve this problem but I'm at loss.

Comment: Do you have information regarding the height of the spacecraft, the velocity of the spacecraft at that height, and the upwards acceleration of the spacecraft when its engine fires up?

Comment: @DavidWhite I was just considering a generic case

Comment: I can provide a derivation, but if you don't have information that matches the variables in the equation that I derive, the equation will be useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going to be brief since I'm on my phone.

Fixed acceleration due to gravity won't work well here. You'll want to use newton's law of gravitation and integrate across r for work. Solve for your rocket's power given it's rate of thrust.

Divide work by power for the time you need to spend with the rocket on, assuming all acceleration is radial.

Since you can't measure time until impact until you've already crashed we need to turn that time into distance.

Initial velocity as a function of the $r_0$ at which you turn on the rocket is easily obtained from Newton's law of gravitation. Retain this function.

Sum the forces and integrate from $r_0$ to $r_{planet}$ for net work as a function of $r_0$. Solve for delta v as a function of the same.

Set $v_i + \Delta v = 0$ and solve for $r_0$.

---

If you have a tangent velocity and you don't care where on the planet you land, just flip and burn as soon as possible to eliminate the tangent velocity. By definition it isn't helping you get any closer.

Comment: Thank you, this is correct. I realize that because it was framed as the impulse of the engine I tried to force everything into terms of momentum and I completely overlooked just putting everything all in terms of energy

Answer (score 0):

It clearly can be done because SpaceX does it consistently with its Falcon 9 rockets (as well as providing the proper horizontal forces to keep the rocket from tipping over). So how can you achieve this?

You mention the thrusters provide a fixed impulse, but - as you state as one of your conditions, the change in the mass of the fuel is not to be considered.  Therefore this is equivalent to a constant upward acceleration from the thrusters - as long as the burn rate remains constant.

You can therefore solve the problem by considering what is needed to accelerate the rocket upward to a velocity that matches its downward velocity at the moment that the thrusters are turned on.

You can achieve this using:  **V<sup>2</sup>=2ad**

where **a** is the upward acceleration of the thrusters minus **9.8m/s<sup>2</sup>** from gravitation.

Rearranging for **d** which represents the height when the thrusters need to be turned on and you have:  **d=V<sup>2</sup>/2a**

where **V** is the velocity of the rocket at the instant the thrusters are turned on.

Comment: I'm sure that SpaceX not only has a calculation for the correct time to fire their descent rocket, but they also have a feedback control system that measures position, velocity, and height above the ground.  Such feedback corrects for things that are unpredictable, such as rocket thrust that is not exactly what was calculated, updrafting air, crosswinds, etc.

Comment: The issue is that the craft is coming from a distance far away that gravitational acceleration is not constant, so V^2=2ad is too simplistic

Comment: @Aggle, the speed of something like the first stage SpaceX booster will probably have to be found by integration, but that booster fires its descent engine very close to the surface of the earth, meaning that it is valid to assume a constant acceleration due to gravity at the point that the descent engine fires up.